# Difference between failures

Tags: mechanical-failure, fatigue

I'm studying about the phenomena that enlargement of the pipe entrance due to particle impingements. Our group calls this phenomena as erosion. But it seems to be fatigue failure in mechanical engineering.
When I search failures in google there're lots of types and seems these theories overlaps each other. For example, fatigue failure is caused by the accumulation of impact fatigue.
So I think mechanism of failure is connected to each other and hard to say which is which. Also the definition is different depending on contexts and industries. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. it is called erosion in the materials science field.

Comment: What's the difference between erosion and fatigue failure in this case?

Comment: fatigue failure is caused by crack propagation during  cyclic stress at significantly below the yield strength of the stressed member. This has absolutely nothing to do with abrasive wear.